# Is there something special you have to do to get large chunks of memory on Windows or in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

This is the call I am making.

```
table  = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (C+1) * (N+1));
```

`C+1*N+1` comes out to be 657,562,500

But this call is returning a `NULL` for me when executed on Windows (indicating it could not allocate that amount of space).
(it works fine with a smaller number and also works fine with larger numbers than this on my Linux box)

The program doesn't really do much before this.

When I look at Task Manager it shows 28.1 GB of available memory.

So I am wondering, is there something I can set in Visual Studio like a compiler flag or something that will allow me to grab large chunks of memory like this?

If my math is correct I believe I am asking for about 1.22GB.

Appreciate any help

Edit:
So apparently I need to run this as a 64-bit application.   Anyone know how to change a c project to 64-bits in visual studio? In configuration parameters under platform  Win32 is the only option.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit Windows system by chance?

Comment: @StephenCanon I would doubt that, given the "available memory" figure.

Comment: Its address space fragmentation. You can turn on large address awareness and run on 64 bit Windows to get another 2GB of address space.

Comment: ok so anyone know how to tell visual studio to build this as a 64 bit application?   I can't find any way to tell it to build a c program as 64 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely have your project settings set to build a 32-bit Application.

While your computer may have tons of free memory, a 32-bit application cannot use more than 2GB.   By my estimate, 4 bytes x 650M is around 2.6 GB.

Try changing your project settings to build for a 64-bit platform.

But still ask yourself why you're allocating so much memory at once.  That could well indicate a program design problem.

Comment: +1, especially your point about the chunk size.  Even on a 64-bit build, it can be problematic to request huge chunks of sequential memory.  Often the available heap is fragmented, and getting long runs of consecutive memory is not always possible.  It is better to chain together lots of smaller blocks (think approximately 100-200 MB chunks) and do a bit of index management.

Comment: it is for a parallelization class. I have to do it that way for various and assorted reasons.  I would normally not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Too long and involved to make it a comment, so here's how you build it as 64-bit on Visual Studio.  I'm on a laptop with VS 2010 rather than 2012, so I may have some details wrong, but this will get you there on 2010 or 2012.

From the IDE, do:

```
Build / Configuration Manager / Active Solution Platform / New...
```

Choose the options shown below.  Now you'll be able to build as 64-bit.

[image]

Comment: That did it.   Thanks

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but really, you should accept abelenky's answer since he addressed your fundamental programming problem.  All I did was get you past an annoyance of the tools you're using.